# Which amazon service should i use to implement time based queue dispatcher (serverless application)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

User submit a csv file which contains time (Interval) with message. I want to submit that message on the time mentioned with message to chat API. I am using DynamoDB to store message and a lambda function which read the message from DynamoDB and one at a time use setTimeout function to publish message on chat. I am using node js to implement that functionality. I also created a amazon API to trigger that lambda fUnction.
But this approach is not working. Can any one suggest me which other service should i use to do same ? Is there any amazon queue service for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context of your question what I understand is that you basically need to create a futuristic timer. A system that can inform you sometime in the future with some metadata to take an action.

If this is the case, on top of my head I think you can use the below solution to achieve your goal:

---

**`Pre-requisites`**: I assume, you are already using Dynamo DB(aka DDB) as a primary store. So all CSV data is persisted in the dynamo and you are using dynamo stream to read the insert and updated records to trigger your lambda function(let's call this lambda function as *Proxy_Lambda*).

Create another lambda function that processes records and sends a message to your chat system(let's call this lambda function as *Processor_Lambda*)

---

**Option 1:** AWS SQS

1. *Proxy_Lambda* reads records from DDB stream and based on the future timestamp attribute present in the record, it publishes a message to [AWS SQS queue with initial visibility timeout equals to the timestamp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html). Sample example: [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/sqs-example-message-visibility-timeout.html). Remember, these messages will not be visible to any of the consumer until the visibility timeout.
2. [Add a trigger for *Processor_Lambda* to start polling from this SQS queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-configure-lambda-function-trigger.html).
3. Once message becomes visible in the queue(after the initial timeout), *Processor_Lambda* consumes the message and send the chat events.

`Result`: You will be able to create a futuristic timer using the SQS visibility timeout feature. Cons here is that you will not be able to view the in-flight SQS message content until the visibility timeout of the message occurs.

Note:  Max visibility timeout can be set for 12 hours. So if your use-case demand a timer for more then 12 hours, you need to add code logic in *Processor_Lambda* to send that message back to queue with new visibility timeout.

---

**Option 2:** AWS Step function (my preferred approach ;) )

1. Crate state machine in [AWS Step function to generate task timers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/task-timer-sample.html) (let's call it *Timer_Function*). These task timers will keep looping between the wait state until the timer expires. Timer window will be provided as an input to this step function.
2. Link *Timer_Function* to trigger *Processor_Lambda* once the task timer expires. Basically, that will be the next step after the Timer step.
3. Connect *Proxy_Lambda* with *Timer_Function* i.e. *Proxy_Lambda* will read records from DDB stream and invoke the *Timer_Function* with message interval attribute present the Dynamo DB record and the necessary payload.

`Result`: A *Timer_Function* that keep looping until the time window(message interval) expires. Which in turn provide you a mechanism to trigger *Proxy_Lambda* in the future(i.e. the timer window)

---

Having said that, now I will leave this up to you to choose the right solution based on the use-case and business requirement.

---